# SQL link 2 columns from different tables

Tags: sql

I have a DB with a `cardata` and a `locations` table. In both tables the column `locations` are similar.

For example London Heathrow has 1800+ rows in the `cardata` table.

To reduce the database size, is it possible to only use a reference/id from the locations table of "London Heathrow" and use it in the `cardata` table instead of so many rows with same location.

[image: cardata table]

[image: locations table]

Comment: You need to research relational database design, specifically the Normal Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Not only possible, but desirable as well. Just imagine the scenario when an airport is renamed, like

London Heathrow -> London Heathrow Airport

In such a situation you would have to run something like

```
update cardata
set Location = `London Heathrow Airport`
where Location = 'London Heathrow';
```

There are chances that there will be a disconnect between the two tables if the Location is changed and the change does not manifest in cardata and your data may be damaged for many possible reasons.

This is how you can resolve this problem:

**Step 1**: add a new column to your table

```
alter table cardata
    add column Location2 smallint not null default 0;
```

Note that here I assume your location will not be nullable. If you want it to be nullable, then you can do something like this;

```
alter table cardata
    add column Location2 smallint;
```

**Step 2**: fill this column with values

```
update cardata
join locations on cardata.Location = locations.`Name`
set cardata.Location2 = locations.Id;
```

**Step 3**: drop your `Location` column

```
alter table cardata
    drop column Location;
```

**Step 4**: rename your `Location2` column

```
alter table cardata
rename column Location2 to Location;
```

**Step 5**: add a foreign key constraint to the table

```
alter table cardata
    add constraint fk_location
        foreign key (Location) references locations(Id)
            on delete cascade
            on update cascade;
```

And now you can get the name of the location along with `cardata` using a join

```
select <your columns>
from locations
join cardata on locations.Id = cardata.Location;
```